# Json can access the URL on the local computer, but not on the server

Tags: java, android, kotlin, server, jsoup

This is the key code.

```
val document = 
    Jsoup
    .connect("http://waipian3.com/search-%E4%BD%A0----------1---/")
    .get()
```

It works successfully in my local computer, but if I package it,and put it works on my server, it works wrong.

I tried to add an agent, but it didn't help.

It show me the `org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL`

Why does this code work differently in different places? Is it because of the configuration of my server?

Comment: Does your server allows this outside request? Or it is blocking all outside traffic?

Comment: It should not be blocking all external traffic, as I have visited many other URLs and they all work, but this one does not.

Comment: This looks to be the only issue to me. Please validate that it's in the whitelist *along with other allowed urls).

Comment: I haven't set this up before and I'm not sure how to do it, so how do I do it please?

Comment: It depends upon the server you are using

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved the problem because the other party blocked my IP